# How to limit the width of a column and make its text wrap

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a RadGrid in my application and whats happening is that if the text in the column of the grid is to long it will not wrap so the grid container will expand and get out of the frame so I would like to make it so that when the text in the column is too long that it wraps, how can I do this?  Here is an example of one of those columns.

```
 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="clientnum" 
 HeaderText="Client Number" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
 AllowSorting="false" />
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following aspx code .

ASPX:

```
<MasterTableView   > 
<ItemStyle   Wrap="True" />
```

Set the width of column to a fixed width, so it will wrap the text after crossing the limits

Comment: Sorry kind of a newbie with rad grids, where would i add that item style tag?

Comment: See reference http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/grid/radgrid-itemstyle-wrap-true-not-working-in-ie8-or-firefox.aspx

Comment: The solution given by ROMIL is right. But if you want to wrap text without space then see reference : http://jayeshgoyani.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-wrap-word-in-radgrids-column-or.html

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best way is to see id of your generated table by firebug and then you can set up width via css. In css file you should write something like this

```
#table_id td{
 width: 50px;/*for example*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding in the HeaderStyle-Width tag?
So like this:

```
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="clientnum" 
    HeaderText="Client Number" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
    AllowSorting="false" HeaderStyle-Width="100"/>
```

Where you replace 100 with the width you want.

Let me know if it works!